# How to convert strings to ints while unpacking object keys with ... spread syntax

Tags: typescript

I'm unpacking a set of Object keys which are strings, but need to get the min value of them as ints... Type script complains about this code:

```
let min = Math.min(...Object.keys(rankingDict))
```

Error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Is there a way to make each value a number as it is unpacked? Or must I just loop over the list and `parseInt()` for each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the `parseInt`, but you can do it inline like this:

```
let min = Math.min(...Object.keys(rankingDict).map(k => parseInt(k)))
```